# In a sublime theme, what scope key defines the color of the cursor?

Tags: sublime-text-2, themes, cursor

I'm trying to change the color of the cursor in a Sumblime theme.

[image]

What scope key defines the color of the cursor in `.tmTheme` file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The color is assigned to the `caret` key in the `settings` dictionary, where other default color definitions like `background` are as well.

It doesn't look like this can be adjusted depending on scope.